# carriage return with for loop in java (beginner)

Tags: java, junit

i'm trying to make a histogram like

```
####################
################
##########################
############
```

and here is my code

```
public String generateHistogramA(List<Thingy>things)
{     
    String a="";
    String b="";
    for(int i=0;i<things.size();i++)
    {
        a="";
        for(int j=0;j<=things.get(i).count;j++)
        {
            a=a+"#";
        }
        b+=a+System.getProperty("line.separator");
    }
    System.out.print(b);

    return b;
}
```

and i have a Junit test as following:

```
@Test
public void testGenerateHistogramA() {
    System.out.println("generateHistogramA");
    Histogram instance = new Histogram();
    String expResult = "##############################################################################################################"+System.getProperty("line.separator")+"####################"+System.getProperty("line.separator")+
            "########################################"+System.getProperty("line.separator")+
            "################################################################################################################################################################" +System.getProperty("line.separator")+
            "################################################################################"+System.getProperty("line.separator");
    String result = instance.generateHistogramA(things);
    assertEquals(expResult, result);
}
```

when i used the method in main it has the same result as the Junit test..however the test just didn't pass when i run it..i don't know what's wrong with it..
please..if anyone know what happened...
thanks!

the test results are shown as following:
        junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: expected:<...####################[
        ####################
        ########################################
  ############################################################################################        ####################################################################
        ]####################...> but was:<...####################[#
        #####################
        #########################################
     ############################################################################################        #####################################################################
        #]####################...>

Comment: When `assertEquals` fails, it gives you a comparison to see the difference.  Can you show us that?

Comment: Why don't you use a debugger to examine `result` and `expResult` immediately before the assertion?

Comment: To avoid the whole issue with the `System.getProperty...`, you can use `String.format("my string here%n")`, and `%n` will be replaced with the correct line separator. It's shorter, too.

Comment: Actually, I find `String newLine = System.getProperty("line.separator");` easier to understand than `String newLine = String.format("%n");`, even though some part of my brain knows that they're equivalent.

Comment: @DavidWallace I have to use this Junit test since this is what the teacher asked for..the original one used System..lineSeparator() but because my computer did not support platform 1.7, i changed it to System.getProperty("line.separator")..and i have tried the String.format("%n")and '\n'..the test still failed..

Comment: OK.  So what did the debugger tell you when you tried my earlier suggestion?

Comment: @DavidWallace just added to the question..thnx for your help!

Comment: As I suspected, you've simply miscounted the hashes.  In the first line, the expected number of hashes in the test is 110 and the actual number of objects in your array is 111.  It looks like there are other lines where the numbers don't match too.  I'm not going to count every line for you - you can do this yourself.

Comment: !!!!!!!....i got it!...thnx..

Answer (score 0):

Just as food for thought or so…

That’s closer to how I would do it. Finding out why imposes the chance to learn something ;-)

```
public String generateHistogramA(List<Thingy> things)
{
    String newLine=System.getProperty("line.separator");
    StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
    for(Thingy thingy: things)
    {
        for(int j=0, count=thingy.count; j<count; j++) sb.append('#');
        sb.append(newLine);
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```